# Access Rails proxy_association.owner from within association method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to access the proxy_association object from within a association's method?

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :user

  def some_function
    # Here I want to access the same user object the association was called on
    # (that holds all already defined global variables), not a newly created object
    # through self.user (where all global variables are reset).

    proxy_association.owner
  end
end
```

**How do I access the object an association was called on from within that association?** Unfortunately, `self.user`returns a new object where all previously set variables are back to defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `:inverse_of` option on the `has_many` association. This will connect the two models in memory when using the association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :accounts, inverse_of: :user
end
```

Source: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Comment: Haha, I've been there too. Glad I could help.